# RD WebAccess and Sharepoint 2003 integration

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint

My company is starting to use the RD WebAccess feature of Windows Server 2008 R2 (previously it was known as TS WebAccess) and we are wondering if it might be possible to integrate it into our Sharepoint site.  The Sharepoint site is on Sharepoint Server 2003.  I have searched through microsoft's TechNet/Knowledgebase as well as Google, and have found absolutely nothing.  What we are mostly looking for is confirmation wether this is possible or not, and any instructions/links to instructions that would explain how to do so.

Comment: seriously?  nothing? at all?